# Developing Chat Bot using Wit.aI

Tags: node.js, heroku, chatbot, wit.ai

I am planning to develop a chatbot using Wit.ai for Android and iOS. I want to have a server where I have the Bot engine. The Bot Engine has several components like Exported application from Wit.ai, calls to weather API, date API etc. When the user sends a message, it is sent to the Wit and it returns back a response. For example, when the user says, "What's the weather in New York, the message is forwarded to Wit which further calls weather API  to fetch weather and returns it back to the bot. Bot in turn forwards to app which acts as the presentation layer."

I am planning to use the following to achieve the above:

1. Heroku to act as the server.
2. Wit.ai as the NLP
3. Planning to integrate app with messenger

Since I am new to this kind of programming and architecting, my questions are very basic. Please bear with that. I have the following questions:

1. Can I have a program uploaded on Heroku which talks to Wit.ai and other APIs? If yes, can someone show a detailed tutorial to call Heroku from app, how to make a call from Heroku to other APIs?
2. I was advised by some to use Firebase which is Baas. Can I achieve more using that?

   With regards,
   Suresh

Answer (score 0):

We use the heroku to getting the https url,and if we got that ,we can set up webhook url in developer.facebook.com .
To understand more,follow [this](https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-witai-tutorial) tutorial.

Remember when you try to test after you set up all,u need to test ur own account(means cant test every facebook account yet.)
To be public ur messenger bot,u need to wait 5 business days at least.

Comment: I tried following the tutorial which you directed. However when I type in 
the following code in my node.js command prompt, I am getting error. I have replaced YOUR TOKEN HERE with my Server access token. What can be done?


curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <YOUR TOKEN HERE>' 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20161122&q=what%20is%20the%20weather%20in%20New%20York'

Comment: curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ABCDKEFJ_bla_bla_bla' 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=what%20is%20the%20weather%20in%20New%20York'

Comment: try just like that bro,

Comment: give me ur key,may be u dun have curl to run on cmd ,i will run for u ,:)